# Twitter APi "code":215,"message":"Bad Authentication data

Tags: php, api, curl, twitter

Receiving error

> "code":215,"message":"Bad Authentication data"

in my `$page var_dump($page);`

I read that friends/exist no longer works for version 1.1 so I need to use friends/lookup to compare if one twitter user has the other twitter user befriended. Code below.

```
    $url = $connection->host = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friendships/lookup.json?screen_name_a=' . $data3 . "&screen_name_b=".$id;
    $page = get_data($url);
    Var_dump($page);
```

I've narrowed it down to my guess that I am missing something in the `$url` variable that needs adding such has `oauth` but I don't know how to write this or if this is causing the error?

Can anyone show an example?

Comment: Facing the same issue. Can any one have any solution for that?